# How to ensure uniqueness when merging separate data sets in Snowflake

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, i'm trying to merge two similar datasets into a single dataset in Snowflake, ensuring uniqueness in the merged dataset..

Dataset1 - GA Goal Dataset

Columns:

```
ID        Unique ID for each record in the dataset
UserID    ID for each user in the dataset
URL       URL the Goal occurrred on
Time      DateTime, aggregated to the nearest minute, that the exit goal occured in
Goals     Number of goals triggered by the row
```

Dataset2 - Internal Web Traffic dataset

Columns:

```
ID        Unique ID for each record in the dataset
UserID    ID for each user in the dataset
URL       URL of the pageview/pageload event
Time      DateTime, to nanosecond, that the pageview/pageload event occurred
```

Known conditions

There can be records in either dataset, that do not exist in the other.

The aim for the 3rd dataset

To create a dataset containing:

```
Dataset1.ID
Dataset2.ID
```

- WHERE there is no duplication of Dataset1.ID
- WHERE there is no duplication of DATAset2.ID
- WHERE every instance of Dataset1.ID and every instance of Dataset2.ID is included in Dataset3, regardless of whether there is a match in the other dataset.

What i have tried so far:

I started with Dataset1, and joined this to Dataset2 based on:

```
UserID
URL
Time (where the time in Dataset2 was within 4 minutes of Dataset1 - this is due to the systems running on different servers and platforms, which introduces a time difference in addition to the aggregated time issue).
```

Where i get multiple hits, i choose the min ID from Dataset 2 for each ID in Dataset 1.

This resulted in instances where multiple IDs from Dataset 1 got assigned the same ID from Dataset2, which i want to prevent.

I havent ried to build this, but the only solution i can think of to overcome this, is to process each record in Dataset1 individually, and identify the ID from Dataset1 - when there is a match, select the lowest ID, and write this into a new column in Dataset 1, then also write the ID from Dataset1 to the newly matched ID from Dataset2 into a new column in dataset2.  Then when i take the next row from Dataset1, only attempt to link to Dataset2 where Dataset1 has not been set in Dataset2 yet.

I hope this is making sense...

Thanks in advance,
Scott

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can try to introduce another internal ordering within the dataset and do a full outer join. So let's say you have:

first dataset: 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4

second: 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3

so you order them:

first dataset: 1(1), 1(2), 2(1), 3(1), 3(2), 4(1)

second: 1(1), 1(2), 1(3), 3(1), 3(2), 3(3)

and match:

```
1(1)-1(1)
1(2)-1(2)
null-1(3)
2(1)-null
3(1)-3(1)
3(2)-3(2)
null-3(3)
4(1)-null
```

is this the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach your solution with normal insert / append. 
A view with max(time) group by ID will reduce the answer set to unique ID. 
You could also insert a binary value for each system in an extra row; let's say 1 for system 1 and 2 for system two. 
Summing up that column will show you where your data was coming from: 1 only in system 1, 2 only in system 2 and 3 for both systems.